# How to automate copy - paste - run .exe file?

Tags: python

As I'm looking into a very basic task automation using python, I'm trying to find a way to automate this process.

1. Copy a exe file from a specific location
2. Paste it in the desktop
3. Run the exe file

Is 'subprocess' module what I should use?

Comment: For step 3, yes. For step 1 & 2 (which are really one step in programming terms; you don't typically think in terms of stateful copies followed by pastes) I'd suggest `shutil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done this before using a bat file :

```
import shutil
import subprocess

shutil.copy2('C:/MyLearning/Test.bat','C:/Users/Desktop') #Copy Test.bat from source ad paste into desktop
subprocess.call([r'C:/Users/Desktop/Test.bat']) #Run Test.bat
```

I believe the same can be done with `.exe` file as long as there are no other dependencies needed to be copied as well for the .exe file to run on desktop